# Load SpriteFont in XNA

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, xna-content-pipeline

I'm planning on my game using multiple backgrounds so I'm trying to use spritefonts to draw the text. Every time I load my spritefont I get a error.

```
Line1 = content.Load<SpriteFont>("Courier New");
Line2 = content.Load<SpriteFont>("Courier New");
```

This is the error I get.

Error loading "Courier New". File not found.

Although this was the font listed on the official microsoft website http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447673.aspx.

Comment: Have you actually imported the font into your project through visual studio?

Comment: try this , its a msdn tutorial to load and using the spritefont . pls check this too if u r begineer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447673.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You have to add new a new SpriteFont item to your content project. Inside the .spritefont file, there is FontName element. Replace the default value with Courier New.

Take note of the asset name of the .spritefont file you added. Because that is the name you should reference inside your game. Assuming you named the asset as courier, you could load the font like this

```
SpriteFont Line1 = content.Load<SpriteFont>("courier");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only load content that's in your Content project. Since there isn't any file with the name "Courier New" (.ttf, or whatever) in your Content project, it's natural you'd get a *File not found* error.

You can't just load system fonts. The example in the official Microsoft website just needed an example font name. For their situation to work, they'd need a "Courier New.ttf" (or something) in the corresponding Content project.